# Why does the typing module export "submodules"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

The `typing` module exports two classes, `io` and `re`, as "pseudo-submodules", reproduced below.  What is the intention of making them look like modules by giving them `__all__`, and adding them to `sys.modules`?

I understand the justification behind excluding them from `__all__`: so that `from typing import *` would not mask `io` and `re` if those are imported.

But why add `'typing.re'` and `'typing.io'` to `sys.modules`?

---

Snippets from [`typing.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/typing.py):

```
import re as stdlib_re

# The pseudo-submodules 're' and 'io' are part of the public
# namespace, but excluded from __all__ because they might stomp on
# legitimate imports of those modules.

# ...

class io:
    """Wrapper namespace for IO generic classes."""

    __all__ = ['IO', 'TextIO', 'BinaryIO']
    IO = IO
    TextIO = TextIO
    BinaryIO = BinaryIO


io.__name__ = __name__ + '.io'
sys.modules[io.__name__] = io

Pattern = _alias(stdlib_re.Pattern, AnyStr)
Match = _alias(stdlib_re.Match, AnyStr)

class re:
    """Wrapper namespace for re type aliases."""

    __all__ = ['Pattern', 'Match']
    Pattern = Pattern
    Match = Match


re.__name__ = __name__ + '.re'
sys.modules[re.__name__] = re
```

Comment: I believe that is just used to maintain structure, so you can using them as `from typing.re import Pattern`.

Comment: Ahhhh okay.  Seems right.  Though arguably, `re.Pattern` and `re.Match` are two very different things.  Would've been a lot simpler to just add them directly to `__all__`

Comment: I believe that is still because of maintaining structure. You know, it is only because you have already known that is `re.Pattern`. If you just see a `typing.Pattern`, won't you be confused? And it also adds flexibility to the future(Assume we have a `somethingelse.Pattern`?)

Comment: @Sraw Eh ... but look at all the other names that `typing` exports: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a9122d183b1fbc4484d72aec69fc0979c7fd91f2/Lib/typing.py#L1215.  I believe this is where saying "Namespaces are a great idea" comes from

Comment: Case # 2 - `queue.Queue` versus `asyncio.Queue`.  Never been frowned upon for stdlib modules to export similar names in my opinion.  But your first comment seems reasonable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original intent was that the typing module would accumulate "typed versions" of many classes in the standard library -- for example, types like the `Pattern` type in `typing.re` or the `BinaryIO` type in `typing.io`.

In that case, it makes sense to try and namespace these "phantom types" into submodules-esque things for organizational purposes. So for example, `typing.re.Pattern` would be the canonical home for the `Pattern` type, and it would be re-exported through `typing.Pattern` for the sake of convenience.

In practice, this vision never quite materialized: I suspect this is in part because the type inference capabilities of PEP 484 type checkers were sophisticated enough to let you avoid having to explicitly provide type hints in a lot of cases, and in part because it ended up just being more convenient to include these types either directly in `typing` or in the stubs corresponding to the relevant standard library module.

So, the decision was made (quite recently, in fact) to just deprecate these two modules: see https://github.com/python/typing/issues/589 and https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/10173. In short, the docs were updated just this last week to never mention `typing.io` and `typing.re` -- the new recommendation is to import the relevant types directly from the `typing` module instead.

Probably in future versions of Python the modules will be removed completely, though they'll likely stick around a bit for backwards-compatibility reasons.